# ICommandHandler not executing for SaveCommandArgs (Visual Studio for Mac Extension)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to create simple extension for **Visual Studio for Mac** which will handle the moment when user saves the document (sample project is on GitHub, [right here](https://github.com/Saratsin/SaveCommandHandlerExtension)).

Here's how looks my implementation of `ICommandHandler<SaveCommandArgs>`:

```
[Export(typeof(ICommandHandler))]
[Name(nameof(SaveCommandHandler))]
[ContentType(StandardContentTypeNames.Code)]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.PrimaryDocument)]
public class SaveCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SaveCommandArgs>
{
    public string DisplayName => nameof(SaveCommandHandler);

    private readonly IEditorCommandHandlerServiceFactory _editorCommandHandlerServiceFactory;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SaveCommandHandler(IEditorCommandHandlerServiceFactory editorCommandHandlerServiceFactory)
    {
        _editorCommandHandlerServiceFactory = editorCommandHandlerServiceFactory;
    }

    public bool ExecuteCommand(SaveCommandArgs args, CommandExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var service = _editorCommandHandlerServiceFactory.GetService(args.TextView);
            Debug.WriteLine($"I am executing something on save with {service.GetType()}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public CommandState GetCommandState(SaveCommandArgs args)
    {
        return CommandState.Available;
    }
}
```

**Good point**: system call the constructor of this handler, when you start editing the first file

**Bad point**: `ExecuteCommand` method never called, as well as `GetCommandState` method

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

I was trying to do all the things according to the documentation on official [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-editor-api/wiki/Modern-Editor-Commanding-API-Revisited) in [github project for visual studio api](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-editor-api)

Unfortunately, there're only samples for quick info and autocomplete features. No samples for `ICommandHandler`-s, haven't found any similar projects for Visual Studio for Mac as well

Comment: It should when you press SAVE

Answer (score 1):

I agree the examples since Microsoft Visual Studio SDK documentation is horrible with no good examples of ICommandHandler.

I tried your exact code in visual studio 2022 on Windows 10 and the ExecuteCommand function is called.

**So your code is fine.**

I think the core problem here is that the ICommandHandler interface structure is somewhat newer and Microsoft did a poor job of properly checking for custom command handlers and adding calls.

I am trying to do a similar thing where I add an ICommandHandler to intercept the GoToDefinition command using an ICommandHandler, using this very similar code I can't get the ExecuteCommand function to fire ever.

I have been able to intercept commands using Microsofts older, yuckier DTE or DTE2 interface.

```
//provider constructor code
var dte2 = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));
dte2.Events.CommandEvents.BeforeExecute += CommandEvents_BeforeExecute;

private static void CommandEvents_BeforeExecute(string guid, int id, object customIn, object customOut, ref bool cancelDefault)  
{   //All events fired here use, the guid you want is likely 
    // Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.CMDSETID.StandardCommandSet97_string
    // With an ID defined in 
    // Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID
    Debug.WriteLine("CommandEvents_BeforeExecute1 " + String.Format(
                "dte2 GUID: {0}\nID: {1}\nIn: {2}\nOut: {3}",
                guid, id, customIn, customOut));
}
```